# What are the uppercase letters in this web page banner?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I designed this banner ages ago for http://www.TheNettles.com and like a putz I've forgotten the font name and I no longer have the font file.

What is the font of the "T" and "N" in this image?  I'm pretty sure the lowercase letters are a different font that I already have, Kelmscott.

[image]

No luck with http://whatthefont.com

Comment: Why not simply ask them??

Comment: @Scott Because I'm the one that put them there 15 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it's definitely Potsdam all the way.  I was confused because there's another Potsdam on the web that's very German Gothic-looking.

WhatTheFont didn't pick it up because I was just submitting the uppercase letters.  Once I gave it the full banner, it identified it.